# Closest spatial position from Lat and Long

Tags: c#, database, gps, gis, geospatial

I have an application that uses the DotSpatial framework to connect to a usb GPS on my laptop. I essentially use it when driving out on site to know where I am.

The application also includes a ShapeFile map as background so that I know where I am.

What I have is:

- I have a database with each road devided into 5m increments with a lat.long location and a road name. (So Col 1 = UniqueID, Col 2 = Location Distance in m (I.e. 0, 5, 10 ...), Col 3 = Road Name, Col 4 = Lat, Col 5 = Long)
- The database is SQLite and have one that I created in Access as well.
- The full DotSpatial framework

What I need to do is the following:

- Work out based on my current lat/long (which I get from the GPS receiver and the GPS.NET part of the software) what the nearest Location Distance in m is from the lat/long locations in the database.

If there are any other suggestions please let me know.

P.S the application needs to be portable so dont want to mess around with SQL Server or PostgrSQL with posGIS etc.

Comment: I suppose you require the calculation to take roads into account? You didn't really ask that, you know...

Comment: While I appreciate your problem this isn't a question, it's a request for someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to get the nearest distance in metres from your current lat/long, the first thing you need to do is perform a coordinate transform.

Most GPS receivers work in WGS84, and assuming this, you can use a library such as [Proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) ([.NET wrapper](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/C-NET-wrapper-updated-td4495444.html)) to convert both your current position and the road position to metres (projected coordinates; either into WGS84 projected, or a local coordinate system based on your geographic location. UTM zones can work quite well, or OSGB if you're based in the UK).

You can find a projection best suited for your needs [here](http://spatialreference.org) (however, as I write this, it's currently down... hence my lack of helpful links at this time. I will edit when it's accessible again).

If you need more help with the GIS side of this, consider paying a visit to [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Once you have your locations in metres, get the distance between them:

```
double distanceX = currentXmetres - roadXmetres;
double distanceY = currentYmetres - roadYmetres;

double Distance = Math.Abs( Math.Sqrt( (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY) ) );
```

Now you can query your database with the value of Distance and find the closest location:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY ABS(Distance - Col 2)
LIMIT 1
```

Note: I don't know the actual name of your table, or columns, so replace "table" and "Col 2" accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, while waiting I got all the parts sorted, but was unsure of how to do the closest location. Makes so much sense now to just order it by small to large. This way I would be able to select any location within a certain distance as well and display multiple closest records.

Answer (score 0):

You need the element in your table where the distance (pythagoras) to your point is closest.

```
select top 1 * from mytable
order by ( (table.lon - lon) * (table.lon - lon) + (table.lat - lat) * (table.lat - lat) )
```

Lon&Lat: position you're at. Skipping the sqrt will speed things up quite a bit too.